# C# array to save data

Tags: c#, arrays

I am new with C# and i have a problem. Actually it's my first year in college and in programming and i have a problem with arrays. I've made a class with 3 constructors and 1 method in Windows Form Application. The problem is that i want to store data from three textBoxes - that the user is typing- into an array of 10 using a button. and i don't know how to do it.

```
public class Employee
{
    private int idnum;
    private string flname;
    private double annual;

    public Employee()
    {

        idnum = 0;
        flname = "";
        annual = 0.0;
    }
    public Employee(int id, string fname)
    {
        idnum = id;
        flname = fname;
        annual = 0.0;
    }
    public Employee(int id, string fname, double ann)
    {
        idnum = id;
        flname = fname;
        annual = ann;
    }

    public int idNumber
    {
        get { return idnum; }
        set { idnum = value; }
    }
    public string FLName
    {
        get { return flname; }
        set { flname = value; }
    }

    public double Annual
    {
        get { return annual; }
        set { annual = value; }
    }
    public string Message()
    {
        return (Convert.ToString(idnum) + "  " + flname + "  " + Convert.ToString(annual));
    }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "an array of 10" ?

Comment: Are you saying you want to store the user's input (textboxes) in an array of size 10?

Comment: Your code has no textboxes nor arrays.  Did you paste the wrong code?

Comment: What do you mean by “annual”? Is it a dollar amount? If so you should use `decimal`, not `double`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should add on this form 3 textboxe elements and name it in a next manner textBoxId, textBoxFLName, textBoxAnnual

Also you have to add a button. Let's call it btnSave
Write an event OnClick for this button. In this method we must read all data which user fill in on the form.

```
List<Employee> allEmployees = new List<Employee>();
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //read user input
        int empId = Int32.Parse(textBoxId.Text);
        string empFlName = textBoxFLName.Text;
        double empAnnual = double.Parse(textBoxAnnual.Text);

        // create new Employee object
        Employee emp = new Employee(empId, empFlName, empAnnual);

        // add new employee to container (for example array, list, etc). 
        // In this case I will prefer to use list, becouse it can grow dynamically
        allEmployees.Add(emp);

    }
```

And you can also rewrite your code in a little bit shortest manner:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int IdNum { get; set; }
    public string FlName { get; set; }
    public double Annual { get; set; }

    public Employee(int id, string flname, double annual = 0.0)
    {
        IdNum = id;
        FlName = flname;
        Annual = annual;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return (Convert.ToString(IdNum) + "  " + FlName + "  " + Convert.ToString(Annual));
    }
}
```